# What is the Euler characteristic of $E_8$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups

What is the Euler characteristic of the compact real form of the Lie group $E_8$?

Comment: Do you know about the relation between vector fields and Euler characteristic (e.g., the Poincare-Hopf Theorem)?

Comment: @JohnHughes Ah, compact Lie groups have zero Euler characteristic. That was a homework once. Whoops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ be a nontrivial left-invariant vector field on $E_8$. Since $X$ is never zero, it has vanishing index sum. By Poincare-Hopf, $\chi(E_8)$ is zero. This works for any compact Lie group.